# Origine n'est pas synonyme d'étymologie

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

L'étymologie est une discipline qui s'attache à retrouver le sens premier d'un mot ou d'une unité syntaxique à partir de ses racines lexicales.
Or, la plupart des questions actuellement taguées [etymologie](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymologie) ne s'intéressent pas au sens premier mais à l'utilisation d'un mot ou d'une expression complète, avec souvent un sens complètement différent du sens premier.

J'ai utilisé un tag [origine-ou-raison](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origine-ou-raison) (dont la dénomination est un peu redondante car *origine* inclut déjà le sens *raison*, mais [origine](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origine) est actuellement un synonyme pour [etymologie](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymologie)) pour regrouper les questions qui s’intéressent à l'origine ou à l'apparition de diverses expressions, indépendamment de leurs racines lexicales. J'ai pour l'instant laissé en suspens la modification des questions déjà taguées [etymologie](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymologie), pour lesquelles je considère que le tag [origine](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origine)/[origine-ou-raison](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origine-ou-raison) serait plus approprié, et les cas où une cohabitation avec [etymologie](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymologie) pourrait être souhaitable. Parmi les candidates (liste non exhaustive) :

- [Le « petit juif » est-il péjoratif ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3169/le-petit-juif-est-il-pejoratif)
- [Pourquoi huit ou quinze jours pour une ou deux semaines?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2758/pourquoi-huit-ou-quinze-jours-pour-une-ou-deux-semaines)
- [Origin of "Rob Peter to pay Paul" and "Déshabiller Pierre pour habiller Paul"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/711/origin-of-rob-peter-to-pay-paul-and-deshabiller-pierre-pour-habiller-paul)
- [Avoir l'âge de raison ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1850/avoir-lage-de-raison)
- [Origine de l'expression « gagner des cacahuètes »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/origine-de-lexpression-gagner-des-cacahuetes)
- [Pourquoi « lambda » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/pourquoi-lambda)
- [D'où vient l'expression « aller en boîte » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3281/dou-vient-lexpression-aller-en-boite)
- [D'où vient l'expression « battre son plein » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1775/dou-vient-lexpression-battre-son-plein)
- [De la monnaie de singe?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1562/de-la-monnaie-de-singe)
- [Quelle est l'origine de l'expression « brûler le dur » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/quelle-est-lorigine-de-la-expression-bruler-le-dur)
- [À quand remonte l'apparition de l'expression « un bain de foule » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3218/quand-remonte-lapparition-de-lexpression-un-bain-de-foule)
- [Apparition de l'accent circonflexe ‘^’](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1017/apparition-de-laccent-circonflexe)
- [Étymologie de « un fou dans une poche »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/tymologie-de-un-fou-dans-une-poche)
- [D'où vient le ù de où ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5804/dou-vient-le-u-de-ou)
- [Qu'est-ce qu'une « file indienne » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/741/quest-ce-quune-file-indienne)
- [Quelle est l'origine de l'expression "Faire le poirier" ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1911/quelle-est-lorigine-de-lexpression-faire-le-poirier)

Cohabitations possibles :

- [Origin of the word "trombone" in the sense of "paperclip"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/248/origin-of-the-word-trombone-paperclip)
- [Quelles sont les durées des mots utilisés dans les expressions ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/quelles-sont-les-durees-des-mots-utilises-dans-les-expressions)
- [About "tour de force"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5733/about-tour-de-force)
- [Avoir un grain. De quel grain parle-t-on ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2584/avoir-un-grain-de-quel-grain-parle-t-on)
- [How did "coucou" (with its original "cuckoo" meaning) become a greeting in French?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/563/how-did-coucou-with-its-original-cuckoo-meaning-become-a-greeting-in-frenc)
- [Origine de "gross malheur"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2351/origine-de-gross-malheur)

Question : Quel tags et synonymes garder (sachant que les renommages sont possibles) ?

Comment: Je trouve le tag (origine-ou-raison) nettement plus confus que le simple (origine). Question intéressante, néanmoins.

Comment: @Romain: Néamoins ? Si j'ai utilisé *origine-ou-raison* c'est par contrainte. Cela dit je me demande maintenant si je ne le préfère pas a *origine* seul, ça clarifie sa portée.

Answer (score 3):

L'étymologie comprend l'étude du sens des unités lexicales, pour ne citer que Wikipédia

> L’étymologie est une discipline diachronique de la linguistique, qui cherche à établir l'origine formelle **et sémantique** d'une unité lexicale, le plus souvent un mot.
>   […]
>   formé sur le mot τό έτυμov "vrai **sens**" […]<sup>[WP](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tymologie), emphasis mine</sup>

je trouve donc un peu exagéré de dire qu'il n'est pas justifié « pour regrouper les questions qui s’intéressent à l'origine ou à l'apparition de diverses expressions » en théorie.

En pratique, il serait peut-être intéressant de disposer d'un tag pour les questions portant purement sur l'évolution de la graphie, comme [etymographie](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymographie) — par exemple pour [Apparition de l'accent circonflexe ‘^’](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1017/apparition-de-laccent-circonflexe) ou [D'où vient le ù de où ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5804/dou-vient-le-u-de-ou) — d'un autre pour les questions liées à l'histoire, — comme [Origin of "Rob Peter to pay Paul" and "Déshabiller Pierre pour habiller Paul"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/711/origin-of-rob-peter-to-pay-paul-and-deshabiller-pierre-pour-habiller-paul) — par exemple [histoire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/histoire)  et de garder [etymologie](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymologie) pour parler des évolutions de sens dues à des phénomènes linguistiques (emprunts, dérivations…), par exemple pour [Origin of the word "trombone" in the sense of "paperclip"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/248/origin-of-the-word-trombone-paperclip).

Comment: Désolé mais je ne crois pas que cet extrait de Wikipédia éclaire grand chose. L'étymologie s’intéresse au sens, oui, on est tous d'accord là dessus je crois

Comment: Pour la dernière suggestion, attention à ne pas confondre Histoire et h(H?)istoire du français, le tag est utilisé pour l'histoire du français (en tout cas c'est ce qui est précisé dans le wiki excerpt).

Comment: Je sais pas, ta question me laissait penser que tu ne voulais pas utiliser [tag:etymologie] pour parler du sens.